# How do you signal an update to a readonly @property which is dependant on children properties?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing

This is a simplified example that should be enough for the question.

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject {
   Person *_owner;
}
   @property (strong) Person *owner;
   @property (readonly) BOOL hasSomething;
@end

@implementation
   // other code here like -init
   - (void)setOwner:(Person *)newOwner
   {
       [_owner removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"stuff"];
       _owner = newOwner;
       [_owner addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"stuff" options:0 context:NULL];
   }
   - (Person*)owner
   {
       return _owner;
   }
   - (BOOL)hasSomething
   {
       return owner.stuff > 0;
   }
   - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)kp ofObject:(id)obj change:(NSDictionary*)ch context:(void*)c
   {
       if ([kp isEqualtToString:@"stuff"]) {
           [self willChangeValueForKey:@"hasSomething"];
           [self didChangeValueForKey:@"hasSomething"];
       }
   }
@end
```

In my example, anything bound to `hasSomething` is not properly notified of a change of value.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**My workaround:**
I initially worked around the issue by binding straight to the value that I wanted to track.  In the example given it would have looked like `arrangedObjects.owner.stuff`.

**My Solution:**
I later revisited the code and discovered that **what I had was essentially correct**.  The idea was to encapsulate the inner working of a hierarchy of objects (which isn't achieve if you bind the whole path like my workaround above).  In the question, I simplified the problem to a hierarchy with two levels : MyClass -> Person.  My code actually involves more levels and a to-many relationship.  One of the elements in the hierarchy wasn't properly observing its children.

---

Denis suggested I take a look at `-automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:` and I did.  From my understanding, you would want to have the method return `NO` in the event you want to send the notification manually within the setter method of the property.  Otherwise, your notifications conflict with the automatic ones.

```
- (void)setHasSomething:(BOOL)newVal
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"hasSomething"];
    // ...
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"hasSomething"];
}
```

Since there's no setter method for a readonly property, having it didn't solve my problem.

---

*Lessons learned: 1) Observe your children properly; 2) Don't over-simplify your problem when asking for help.*

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-SW3

You have to add

```
+ (BOOL)automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:(NSString *)theKey {

    BOOL automatic = NO;
    if ([theKey isEqualToString:@"hasSomething"]) {
        automatic = NO;
    } else {
        automatic=[super automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:theKey];
    }
    return automatic;
}
```